# List - dictionary binding in java

Tags: java, binding

I am building a library that has list of objects and dictionaries (maps) that relate objects from a list to objects in other list

i.e. (in pseudo code):

```
// list of buses
buses = [Bus1, Bus2, Bus3]

// list of Loads
loads = [Load1, Load2, Load3, Load4]

// dictionary / map
bus_loads = Bus1:{Load1, Load2}, Bus2:{Load3}, Bus3:{Load4}
```

I am using Java to program this library.
Is there any binding mechanism that allows me to delete an element in a list, delete the dictionary entry and the corresponding elements in the related list?

For example, if by deleting `Bus1` in the buses list, I would delete the `Bus1:{Load1, Load2}` entry in the dictionary and also `Load1` and `Load2` in the loads list?

The straight forward solution is to create a method to delete the objects and take care of this, but I would like to know if there is a more efficient or straight forward manner.

Code example:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class List_dict_list_binding {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Create the example
        Bus bus1 = new Bus("bus1");
        Bus bus2 = new Bus("bus2");
        Bus bus3 = new Bus("bus3");

        ArrayList<Bus> buses = new ArrayList<>();
        buses.add(bus1);
        buses.add(bus2);
        buses.add(bus3);

        Load load1 = new Load("load1");
        Load load2 = new Load("load2");
        Load load3 = new Load("load3");
        Load load4 = new Load("load4");

        ArrayList<Load> loads = new ArrayList<>();
        loads.add(load1);
        loads.add(load2);
        loads.add(load3);
        loads.add(load4);

        Map<Bus, ArrayList<Load>> dict = new HashMap<>();
        dict.put(bus1, new ArrayList<>());
        dict.put(bus2, new ArrayList<>());
        dict.put(bus3, new ArrayList<>());

        dict.get(bus1).add(load1);
        dict.get(bus1).add(load2);

        dict.get(bus2).add(load3);

        dict.get(bus3).add(load4);

        System.out.println("Original");
        System.out.println(buses);
        System.out.println(loads);
        System.out.println(dict);

        // DELETE bus1
        buses.remove(bus1);

        System.out.println("Deleted bus1");
        System.out.println(buses);
        System.out.println(loads);
        System.out.println(dict);
    }

}

class Bus {

    public String ID;

    Bus(String id) {
        ID = id;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return ID;
    }
}

class Load {

    public String ID;

    Load(String id) {
        ID = id;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return ID;
    }
}
```

The output is this:

```
Original
[bus1, bus2, bus3]
[load1, load2, load3, load4]
{bus3=[load4], bus1=[load1, load2], bus2=[load3]}
Deleted bus1
[bus2, bus3]
[load1, load2, load3, load4]
{bus3=[load4], bus1=[load1, load2], bus2=[load3]}
```

Comment: Yes Santi Peñate-Vera you can use liste.remove(index); or  liste.remove(Object);

Comment: Indeed, but will that remove the entries from the other objects?

Comment: I think in your case you need something like HashMap              Map<String, List<String>> dic = new HashMap<>();

Comment: I added a working example, but the behaviour is not there by default, so either a function to explicitly delete the references is needed, or something simpler, which is the point of my question.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no simpler way. 
Even though it is the same Bus in both "buses" and "bus_loads", Each data structure stores a different "pointer" to this Bus, and there is no connection between those "pointers". So, deleting one pointer is not enough. You must also delete the other yourself.

It is the same for when you want to cascade the deletion of Loads of the deleted Bus.

Answer (score -2):

You could use a backed collection such as TreeSet or TreeMap. With backed collections any changes in the set or map are synchronised. This can be achieved by using TreeSet.subSet():

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html#subSet(E,%20boolean,%20E,%20boolean)

I hope that helps.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on your answer, I don't see how it is relevant.